# pacbio demultiplexing issue

Tags: pacbio, demultiplexing

I was wondering if there is a way to provide pacbio lima demultiplexing only a barcode, and let  lima demux sample even if only one end has the barcode, not both?

Comment: Can you please explain more about the context of your problem? What are you trying to do with the demultiplexing; what is the ultimate aim of the analysis?

Comment: Some examples of what your data look like might help

Answer (score 0):

PacBio lima need both 5'end and 3' end barcodes. You can have a unique barcode in one end and multiple on the other end; but it need two barcodes.